# iOS: occasional loss of UI animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, transition

It' hard to reproduce, but here's the gist:

I have an app with various UI transitions, e.g. sliding drawer, segue transitions with crossfade or cover left/right. Sometimes, when user login with Facebook (app jumps to Facebook app, then back, after getting permission), all the UI animations will be lost.

The end result is like having all UI animations with transition time zero. All functionalities are still there, but the experience is painful. Restarting the app will get the animations back. Has anybody observe the same and maybe have some hints?

Comment: Only happens after returning from facebook app? How about the switching to background (home button pressed) or maybe opening a control center/notification center?

Comment: Background or notification center no problem. Facebook switch may trigger it, but not consistently. One case is that when building in dev mode, no problem, but for ad hoc distribution, it happens sometimes.

Comment: Hmm it's pretty random. Most recent one happened on XCode7 AdHoc build on iOS9. Back in XCode6 it happened before as well. Currently XCode7+iOS8 seems OK

Comment: Oh, anything can happen on iOS9. I'd wait for 9.1 instead of trying to find the cause

Comment: Thanks, finger crossed.

Comment: Well, this is not likely iOS9 issue, maybe I'm trying to update some background thread where actually i should use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}, I'll check more and see.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code when view willAppear

```
if(![UIView areAnimationsEnabled])
   [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and format your code.